# Prove the number of computations produced by the Nth fibonacci number

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, algorithms, induction, recursive-algorithms

Given the generic Fibonacci function:

```
procedure fib(integer: n):
    if n = 0  return 0
    else if n = 1  return 1
    else return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

Prove the number of computations $C(n) = F(n + 2) + F(n - 1) - 1$ by induction.

The problem also gives:

$C(0) = C(1) = 1$ (base case)

and

$C(n) = C(n - 1) + C(n - 2) + 1$ (The number of computations recursively)

The basis step is given for $C(0)$ and $C(1)$.

The induction step is where I am confused. The answer in the back of the book says something along the lines of "the proof is simple", and offers no further explanation.

I am used to straightforward induction proofs and I'm not sure how to go about solving a recursive algorithm through induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for the inductive step, assume it is true for some $k>1$, i.e. $C(k) = F(k+2)+F(k-1)-1$. We must show that
$$
C(k+1) = F(k+3)+F(k)-1.
$$
But note that since $k>1$, the last case in the algorithm is activated, and computing it requires
$$
\begin{split}
C(k+1)
 &= C(k)+C(k-1)+1 \quad \text{from the algorithm itself} \\
 &= [F(k+2) + F(k-1) - 1] + [F(k+1)+F(k-2)-1] + 1 \\
 &= F(k+2) + F(k+1) + F(k-1) + F(k-2) + 1 \\
 &= F(k+3) + F(k) + 1 \quad \text{by properties of Fibonacci sequence}
\end{split}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

From induction hypothesis, we have $$C(n-1) = F(n+1)+F(n-2)-1$$

Also, write down the expression for $C(n-2)$.

After which, write $$C(n)=C(n-1)+C(n-2)+1,$$

substituting $C(n-1)$ and $C(n-2)$ with the expressions that you have just found. Also, use the property of fibonacci sequence, $F(n)+F(n+1)=F(n+2)$.

Comment: Thanks, it makes a lot of sense. I'm marking @gt6989b as the correct answer, just because it has a full proof. The way you described the steps to prove it I would've been able to solve it easy, thanks.